# US International layout doesn't input 'ç' with Alt+C on Chrome only

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

I'm using the US International keyboard layout to be able to write letters with accents. Everything works fine but for a reason I don't understand, Chrome doesn't seem to like the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination that should display a 'ç'.

Every other key works. I can also display the 'ç' in every other program including Safari but on Chrome nor on Firefox (the shortcut works fine in MS Word, Safari, TextEdit, VSCode, ...

Any idea on what to look for here? I didn't see anything on the Chrome settings but maybe I'm wrong...

I'm using 10.15.7 and the latest version of Chrome (90)

Comment: Try the regular US layout instead, ç is still on the same Opt/C, the only real difference is the Int PC layout has two 'always on' dead keys [emulating the way Microsoft does it], rather than accessing then with opt/e or opt/`

Comment: @Tetsujin that's really weird. Switching to standard US layout has the same issue. ALT+C works on a lot of applications but not on Chrome... (I tried restarting Chrome wihout luck).

Comment: I don't really use chrome, but I quickly tested v89 as it was updating then 90 once it had finished. I cannot repro the issue, ç works on UK & US layouts. All I can think is it may be some extension you have installed in Chrome.

Comment: I used Ukulele app to create a layout based on the US international so I can put the ç on another key (and it now works) but I'll leave this question opened for now to see if anyone has an idea about why my "c" key could be seen as "dead" from Chrome's POV.